# Sitecore 9 Forms Creation

Tags: sitecore-forms

Is there any way for creating a simple form in Sitecore through dynamically using code so that it appears in the Sitecore Forms UI?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details into your question. You want to have code that's generates form using Sitecore forms and then it appears in Sitecore Forms UI? Is this correct? Why you would like to create form dynamically using code?

Comment: yes your correct..

Comment: You want to have code that's generates form using Sitecore forms--exactly i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though, I don't see the use case for your question, a form is just contructed by a tree of sitecore items. So in theory, you could create those items through code, like you would create other sitecore items with the Sitecore API.

[image]

To make it appear in the Forms UI, you would need to index them to the master index, as the list is builded from the master index.

If you would like to see the structure of the items you need to create, I would suggest to create a sample form through the UI, and get a look at the created items.

Comment: I want to migrate WFFM  to Sitecore forms,if they used textbox i need to convert into Sitecore 9 forms textbox via code.So just i need to create a items like as usual in sitecore..is this creates a form?

Comment: A noble cause to create a converter tool. :-) Good luck, but I think it will be challenging because there are major differences in architecture and functionality between WFFM and Sitecore Forms.

Comment: okay.Thanks for your info and reply Bart..!

Comment: It might be easier to actually just have a person migrate the forms from one form to another. Unless you have 10,000 forms or some other ridiculous number of them.

Comment: Sitecore Powershell Extensions are your friend here - https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx

Comment: i want to share one more thing here , no need to rebuild index, i checked after creating through API , form is visible in content editor..

Comment: @RAJASEKARANR how about listing in Form Module, is the created form is visible there too without index rebuild?

Comment: yeah ..tree too is visible without rebuilding index.