# Sitecore 9 Forms API

Tags: sitecore-forms

Is there any way to access a Sitecore 9 form field properties through code ?.i need to add CSS class to Text box..etc via code.
Any Suggestion?

Comment: Did you try it via using the parent class, and making all the CSS generic for the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question builds further on your previous question regarding Forms creation through code. [Sitecore 9 Forms Creation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14900/sitecore-9-forms-creation)

There is no real dedicated API for Sitecore Forms as in fact everything is stored as sitecore items and you can use the standard API to access them.

The fields you are referring to are just properties of your items. You can access them as any other sitecore field.

[image]

Do note that on submit action, it might be a bit more complex since, most information is in a json string, stored in the parameters property.

[image]